# Azure B2C Rotate Policy key through script

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

We are using API key to call custom API from B2C custom policy as part of seamless migration. We are looking for automated way to rotate policy key.

I have tried following C# code using graph client and its updating new key but wanted to know if there is PS command to perform similar kind of operation?

C# code:

```
var result = graphClient.TrustFramework.KeySets["B2C_1A_keyset"]
                .UploadSecret(use, k, nbf, exp)
                .Request()
                .PostAsync().Result;

            if (result != null)
                Console.WriteLine("Updated policy key secret");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow this guidance on best practices [Policy key management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/policy-keys-overview#key-rollover) with Azure AD B2C.

Use any sample that does REST API calls via C# and follow these two docs to call the correct Microsoft Graph endpoint:

- [Keysets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/microsoft-graph-operations#trust-framework-policy-keyset)
- [Policy keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/microsoft-graph-operations#trust-framework-policy-key)

Comment: Thanks for links I think we can call these rest endpoints from PS and use it in automated process.